# Ustream channels Jquery plugin gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am writing a `plugin` for one of my website I just want to embed my **Ustream channels** on my website I write a very basic code but this code is not working as expected Please see this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u6JF.png) and here is my code what I have write so far.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 playground">
    <iframe id="main_player" src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/21427417?html5ui&amp;autoplay=true&amp;volume=90&amp;controls=true&amp;showtitle=true" height="550" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>           
</div>
```

**Channel Code**

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="thumb_me">
      <iframe id="" src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/21427417?html5ui&amp;autoplay=true&amp;volume=0&amp;controls=false&amp;showtitle=false" height="250" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
      <div class="desc text-center">Channel 1</div>
      <div class="click_me"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="thumb_me">
      <iframe id="" src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/21472172?html5ui&amp;autoplay=true&amp;volume=0&amp;controls=false&amp;showtitle=false" height="250" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
      <div class="desc text-center">Channel 2</div>
      <div class="click_me"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="thumb_me">
      <iframe id="" src="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/21472913?html5ui&amp;autoplay=true&amp;volume=0&amp;controls=false&amp;showtitle=false" height="250" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
      <div class="desc text-center">Channel 3</div>
      <div class="click_me"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By Default the First video will auto play in `div PLAYGROUND` with sound and all other channels will be inside small thumbnails Auto play and No Sound.

I just want that when someone **clicked** on thumbnail, Thumbnail `iframe` video Should Animate to Playground and take place of main video without reload the `iframe` and play where it was in Thumbnail and add an `attribute &volume=100` to `iframe` src.

Here is the link of [current page](http://www.judocanada.org/if/).

Please share your ideas with me so I can get it done.